# In ruby/grit, how do I get a list of files changed in a specific commit?

Tags: ruby, commit, show, grit

I want a list of files affected by a certain commit in git. Through the command line, I can do this with:

git show --pretty="format:" --name-only (sha)

But how can I do this through Grit in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `your_commit.diffs` which returns an array of `Grit::Diff` instances. `Grit::Diff` has `a_path` and `b_path` properties.

Some (untested) example code:

```
paths = [];
@commit.diffs.each do |diff|
    paths += [diff.a_path, diff.b_path]
end
paths.uniq!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Grit's git module employs method_missing to shell out, you can also try:

grit.git.show({ :pretty => :format, :name_only => true}, sha)